# function argument to call a function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, parameter-passing

I am trying to understand the below simple syntax which I wrote and it works fine. However, I am trying to understand that in `def transform_data(data)`, I am passing data as a parameter and after this, I am using the same parameter to call `drop` function of pandas. Usually, we call a function using object but is it possible to call a function using function parameter or I am wrong.

```
import pandas as pd 

def read_csv_file(file_reading):
 file_contents = pd.read_csv(file_reading)
 dropped_column = transform_data(file_contents)
 save_to_file = write_file(dropped_column)
 return save_to_file

def transform_data(data): #<-- This data is parameter
 processed_data = data.drop("column_name", axis=1) #<--can we call function using parameter
 return processed_data
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
 df = read_csv_file('budget-report.csv')
 print(df)
```

Sorry, If this question seems stupid but I am curious to know these little things before jumping onto big things. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The value of the parameter is an object.

Comment: What do you think `data` is if it's not the object that was passed as an argument from `read_csv_file()`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case `data` is a Pandas Dataframe (`pd.DataFrame`). A function argument is just a variable like any other which can be a reference to an object, so yes, you can certainly call a function.

If there is any question about this you can inspect the argument to see what it is. Start by adding the following print statement

```
print(type(data))

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

You'll see from that printout that it's a DataFrame. You could then quickly google the docs for a DataFrame object to learn more about what you can do with it:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

We can see from the docs that `drop` is a function provided.

You could also have looked at what functions are defined on that object:

```
print(dir(data))
```

That shows all of the attributes and functions provided by the object. The list will be long, but you'll notice all of the normal pandas DataFrame functions show up, including `drop`.

---

As a bonus discussion, you might also benefit from Python typing. You can specify the data type you expect in your function. In Python typing is really just a form of documentation. This form of the function definition explicitly states that the function expects a `pd.DataFrame` object. You might also do a test for that to be sure you received what you expected:

```
def transform_data(data: pd.DataFrame): #<-- This data is parameter
  assert isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame), f'data is expected to be a DataFrame, found {type(data)} instead.'
  processed_data = data.drop("column_name", axis=1) #<--can we call function using parameter
  return processed_data
```